# Toast is not displaying in catch block

Tags: android, toast

Hi ! I'm trying to display a mesage when  the network is off or the server is not responding. My messsage is visible in LOG  but does not show on screen (is not toasted). I have a sample code which works fine but my code is not.

```
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;

public class AgAppHelperMethods  extends Activity  {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = null;
    private static AgAppHelperMethods instance = null;
    public static String varMobileNo;
    public static String varPinNo;

    String[][] xmlRespone = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.agapphelpermethods);
    }

    protected AgAppHelperMethods() {}

    public static AgAppHelperMethods getInstance() 
    {
        if(instance == null) 
        {
            instance = new AgAppHelperMethods();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static String getUrl () 
    {
        String url = "https://demo.accessgroup.mobi/";
        return url;
    }

    public  String[][] AgAppXMLParser(String parUrl) 
    {       
        String _node,_element;
        String[][] xmlRespone = null;
        try {
            String url = AgAppHelperMethods.getUrl() + parUrl;
            URL finalUrl = new URL(url);

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(finalUrl.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList list=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
            _node=new String();
            _element = new String();
            xmlRespone = new String[list.getLength()][2];

            for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++)
            {
                Node value=list.item(i).      getChildNodes().item(0);
                _node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
                _element=value.getNodeValue();
                xmlRespone[i][0] = _node;
                xmlRespone[i][1] = _element;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error  server not responding " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CONNECTION ERROR  FUNDAMO SERVER NOT RESPONDING", e);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I show my toast message on the screen? Thanks.

Comment: Try to use `AgAppHelperMethods.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` in your `Toast`

Comment: Please stop asking people for their email addresses. Nobody on here is your personal helper.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. You can do something like this

```
boolean flag=true;//take globally

//working thread
.
.
.

  catch (Exception e)
  {
    flag=false;
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CONNECTION ERROR  FUNDAMO SERVER NOT RESPONDING", e);
  }
```

Once your working thread gets over check the flag value and show the Toast.

```
//Main Thread
 if(!flag)
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error  server not responding " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

note: If you still want to show in NonUI Thread then you can use `Handler` or `runOnUiThread()`

Comment: Why *can't* it be done in a `catch`? I see no logic difference here or reason for the extra logic ..

Comment: @pst http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare He is updating UI from a worker thread. He need to call it from within the main thread.

Comment: .. not related. Talks about issues with toast on *different threads*, of which the above code *does not change*.

Comment: this bloolean is declaer in button press method??

Comment: hotvery spicy  sir can u give me ur email address i cn mail u my full code so u easily understand my prob

Comment: @user1513889 its simple, you just need to show `Toast` on Main Thread or can use `Hander` or `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: can any one give me ur email address? i mail u full code how the aplication flow so u understand easily my need

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Toast.makeText(AgAppHelperMethods.this, "error  server not responding " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CONNECTION ERROR  FUNDAMO SERVER NOT RESPONDING", e);
```

Comment: Is there still a problem? You can post your code here, we all want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you pass right context, for example:

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this , "error  server not responding " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this hasn't been answered yet. It appears to me all you need to do is run the Toast on the UI thread. Thus, in your catch block:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    Toast.makeText(...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare globally write it in oncreate and only show in catch block.

```
    Toast toast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        toast = Toast.makeText(ActivityDeliverables.this, "Server is not working, please contact with admin.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   }


          try{
             } catch (Exception e) {

                toast.show();
            }
```

Comment: is not working, here is error : **Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

Answer (score 0):

This method is working for me if someone still need help:

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(Runnable { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })
```

Answer (score -1):

check this its working fine for me

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_finder);

        show();             
    }

    public void show()
    {
         try
         {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException() ;
         }

         catch(Exception e)
         {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: no it's not, please correct your answer here is why : **Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**